# How to set an Inline figure matching the text height?

Tags: graphics, inline, height

I want to put a very small figure inline with text. The figure must have the same height as the line it is positioned in. I have this:

```
Some text... \includegraphics[height=\baselineskip]{picture.png} ... some more text.
```

This, however, makes the figure slightly too large, filling the whole space up to the bottom of the line above. I want the figure to be only as high as the capital letters of my font. What's the right way to do this?

Comment: Try `height=1em`.

Comment: According to http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Lengths#Units `em` is *roughly the width of an 'M' (uppercase) in the current font*. So it is not what you want. Neither `ex` *roughly the height of an 'x' in the current font*. Also see the Examples here http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Lengths#Examples

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Tell TeX that the figure should be as high as a “B”:

```
Some text... 
\includegraphics[height=\fontcharht\font`\B]{picture.png} 
... some more text.
```

You probably want to define a special command for this:

```
\newcommand{\mychar}{%
  \begingroup\normalfont
  \includegraphics[height=\fontcharht\font`\B]{picture.png}%
  \endgroup
}
```

and type your paragraph as

```
some text \mychar{} some text
```

If you plan to use this also in titles or captions, it's better to say

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\mychar}{%
  \begingroup\normalfont
  \includegraphics[height=\fontcharht\font`\B]{picture.png}%
  \endgroup
}
```

Comment: this is exactly it. `height=1em` is not exactly what I wanted (as it is roughly the width of an 'M' as @Sigur posted)

Comment: You might possibly want to end the group begun, but +1 for the `%` at end of lines:-)

Comment: This is a good solution, but if I use this command in Beamer, an image is stretched horizontally in uncontrollable manner, so it is important to add a width parameter to avoid the issue.

Comment: @VladimirS. I can't see the problem. Perhaps a new question is in order.

Comment: Just for the record @egreg , what does **\fontcharht\font`\B** mean ?

Comment: @Etsaf The height of a B in the current font. In the setting of my answer, the normal document font.

Comment: How do you have it so that you can substitute in any image?

Answer (score 16):

This is what `\scalerel*` does... it scales its first argument to the same vertical footprint as its second argument, in this case the letter "B".

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{scalerel}
\begin{document} 
This is an inline \scalerel*{\includegraphics{SelfPortrait}}{B} photo.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**edit:** as pointed out by @egreg, the approach below works only for the normal font size. I'll keep it for historical reasons.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\newlength{\myMheight}
% Create the reference text for measures
\settoheight{\myMheight}{M}

\begin{document}

foo\includegraphics[height=\myMheight]{foo.pdf}foo

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You don't need the box, just `\settoheight{\myMheight}{M}`

Comment: See You may like to have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42114/4918 ;-)

Comment: This will always use the same height independently of the context: in a `\Large` context it wouldn't be correct.

Comment: @Sigur Yes, it was.